# Switching from http to https causes CSS issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, https

I am running an OSCommerce/Wordpress website which has been working fine with SSL and page changes until I checked in IE and Chrome.

When using these two browsers, when I go from a regular page to a secure one, some of my CSS changes. The width of the page container changes from 74.923em(or about 960px) to 1198px, but the source still says 74.923em. Some of my H2 tags change from the style that I've given it back to default.

Again, this only happens in Chrome and IE when I switch to a secure page and it stays changed every page after that whether it is secure or not. Is there something wrong with how I've linked the CSS? The rest of the page looks the same except that it has been spread out by the container's width.

Firefox, Safari and Opera work fine.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Answer (score 1):

Is this possibly because of [unsecure file linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725523/how-to-include-css-and-js-files-via-https-when-needed)

You can't reference a http source from https.

Comment: well, how come the rest of the page is fine but 2 CSS IDs choose not to work? Just seems odd...

Comment: Ok I've changed the stylesheet link, by the way, still no difference.