# third party Chart api Not working in Https

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, azure

i am Using a third party Chart `API` [Simile](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) for showing the Charts.this works fine til i use `HTTP`, but since i moved over to `HTTPS`: this chart API failed to load,

No chart rendered for HTTPS communication but same works for HTTP ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the 'hosted' timeline api? I mean referencing: http://api.simile-widgets.org/timeline/2.3.1/timeline-api.js. This might be the reason why it's not working:

1. If your application is running under HTTPS you'll need to include a HTTPS version of that script (or remove the "HTTP:", use //api.simile-widgets.org/timeline/2.3.1/timeline-api.js instead).
2. Maybe you didn't notice, but there is no HTTPS version of the hosted API (you'll get a **Not Found** error when accessing it through HTTPS).

In order to solve the issue I suggest you upload the JS file to blob storage and reference it like this from your application:

**//youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/timeline-api.js** (without http: or https:)

Answer (score 0):

If you load the chart API from an external non-HTTPS URL most browsers will (per default) prevent loading the external (I assume) JavaScript content. You either have to host the API yourself or load it from an external host with a valid SSL certificate.

Questions like [How to Include CSS and JS files via HTTPS when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2725523/468244) show ideas on how to handle this situation when supporting HTTP and HTTPS.