# CS-Cart Banner Slideshow not working in https

Tags: https, slider, slideshow, nivo-slider, cs-cart

Hi I have a question in regards to CS-cart version 2.2.4 Banners Slideshow.
It uses Nivo Slider and the banner works fine on the normal site (http://www.smilefile.com.au/) but as soon as it goes to the secure URL it breaks (https://www.smilefile.com.au/).
The image to the links don't seem to be broken but it seems the javascript isn't running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously, you include some javascript files from external domain by **http**, it causes the secure problem:

`[blocked] The page at https://www.smilefile.com.au/ ran insecure content from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js.`

Try to read this question, it should help.
[How to Include CSS and JS files via HTTPS when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725523/how-to-include-css-and-js-files-via-https-when-needed)

Comment: I changed the link to //ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js and that fixed the issue. Many thanks