# Javascript function "not defined" in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using a plugin, and the docs say to use the following script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/dist/email.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("user_X");
   })();
</script>
```

But in Firefox, and only Firefox I'm getting:

> ReferenceError: emailjs is not defined

**UPDATE:**

Looks like it's having a certificate issue:

> cdn.emailjs.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is
>   unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate
>   certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported.
>
> (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

Comment: Could you try using a local copy of `email.min.js` and see if the error is still there?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Firefox 44.0.2.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @FelixKling, essentially it can't find a definition for emailjs which is being called in the function.I believe this means the JS file hasn't been included properly.

Comment: Try removing `https`. use `http` instead.

Comment: @Redmega Both are available, and using `https` where possible is generally a good idea to avoid tampered scripts. Take the recent Chinese DDOS attack on Github for example.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara True. Sometimes it tends to cause issues when running locally/behind a proxy. Perhaps he should use [protocol-relative paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725523/how-to-include-css-and-js-files-via-https-when-needed)

Comment: Try downloading `email.min.js` to your local server and give local server path in `script src` and see if you are able to run.