# HTTPS not showing .html file correctly, but when unsecure the data shows up

Tags: html, https, mixed-content

My site goes through HTTPS, and it says some content is not secure, so when I show unsecured items the HTML page shows up fine.

When in HTTPS though, the page looks incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Thats because the links (eg: stylesheets, js files) in your page are requested through an http connection. Making them to be requested through https will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your css isn't loading when you're connecting via https.

Is it possible you're not using protocol-relative paths?
If your paths are specific to http they won't load when connecting via https:

Replace paths in this format:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/style.css">
```

with paths in this format

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/style.css">
```

See here for more discussion: [How to Include CSS and JS files via HTTPS when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725523/how-to-include-css-and-js-files-via-https-when-needed)

Comment: No problem! You can click the checkmark under the voting arrows to mark an answer as accepted.