# BootStrap Glyphicons don't show while using HTTPS protocol

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

I'm using BootStrap in the Grails application , but i'm facing weird thing , when use `HTTP` in my page ex:`http://www.mypage.com` Glyphicons are working fine , but when i use `HTTPS` they disappear  ex:`https://www.mypage.com`

while using `HTTP`:
[image]

Using `HTTPS`:
[image]

i'm calling them using :

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"
rel="stylesheet">
```

any advice to make working fine while using `HTTPS` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Some http resources may be blocked when using https protocol.

Comment: You mean like this answer already provides?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725523/how-to-include-css-and-js-files-via-https-when-needed ;)

Comment: @Marcin C i tried what you mentioned but still the same issue

Comment: @Sherif did you hard refreshed page? ctrl+f5 or similar to remove wrong references from browser's cache.